# Enterprise Library logging into database is very slow

Tags: enterprise-library

I'm using enterprise library for logging web page events. Because page is load balanced I have to store logs in database on different server (requirement). Sadly, I found storing around 20 entries per page request is very slow (adds additional ~10s). Can anybody explain why this happens and how to fix it.

P.S. I'm using default pooling settings in logging database connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that Enterprise Library doesn't throw exception when logging database is unavailable.

When it can't connects to database it looks like on the first attempt it tries to connect to database and when it doesn't get a response it remembers that database is not available and ignores the logging next time.